# jQuery create and remove <div> by click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I try to wirte a function, which enables the user to create a  when he clicks on a certain area of the site, and when he clicks on that created div again, it gets deleted. Somehow I can only create divs and when I click them, a new one is created instead removing of the clicked one. I also implemented a function in which the user can determain if he wants to create a div or delete a div.

```
<!--changed #button to #conten-->
<div id='content'></div>
<button id='btn'></button>



var i = 0;
var remove = false;
$('#content').click(function(e) {
    $('<div></div>').attr({
        'id' : i
    }).addClass('circle').css({
        'top' : e.pageY - 20,
        'left' : e.pageX - 20
    }).appendTo('#button');
    i++;
});

$('.circle').click(function (){
    if(remove == true){
        $(this).remove();
    }
    else{
        //just to see if it was clicked
        $(this).css({'background-color': 'red'});
    }
});
$('#btn').toggle(function() {
    $('#btn').text('add');
    remove = true;
}, function() {
    $('#btn').text('remove');
    remove = false;
});
```

Comment: Where is "remove" initialised ? does the background change to red ?

Comment: A couple of comments: `cicrle` is probably not the spelling you were looking for and you don't declare `remove` anywhere. Otherwise, what's the question?

Comment: @lonesomeday probably all it needs !

Comment: can you add you html as well? trying to replicate you issue but I do not know what #btn is for example. also cicrle is mispelled!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/CutPp/

```
var i = 0;
var remove = true; // added this 
$('#button').click(function(e) {
    $('<div/>').attr({
        'id' : i
    }).addClass('circle').css({
        'top' : e.pageY - 20,
        'left' : e.pageX - 20
    }).appendTo('#area'); // append to new container
    i++;
});

$('#area').on('click','.circle',function (){ // corrected spelling and changed to on()
    if(remove){  // no need to check for == true
        $(this).remove();
    } else {
        //just to see if it was clicked
        $(this).css({'background-color': 'red'});
    }
});

$('#btn').toggle(function() {
    $('#btn').val('add');
    remove = true;
}, function() {
    $('#btn').val('remove');
    remove = false;
});
```

I did the following :

- added a variable - `remove`
- used [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of click as the divs are added to the DOM after the click was bound
- sorted the spelling of circle
- created a container for the newly created divs

My example HTML

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="New Div"/>&nbsp;<input type="button" id="btn" value="Add"/><br/>
<span id="area"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

i see three problems (withouth seeing the markup it's difficult to be more precise:

- you didn't set remove so `if(remove == true){` is always false
- the created div is appended to the element with id = `button` and so when you click on the div you also trigger the click event on the parent() (which creates another div
- you are calling toggle on an object with id = `btn`, shouldn't it be `button`?

Ok i edited your code, it still makes little sense because it's not clear what you want to do:

```
<button id='button'>Add</button>
<button id='btn'>Toggle</button>
<div id="result"></div>

var i = 0;
var remove;
$('#button').click(function(e) {
    $('<div></div>').attr({
        'id' : i,
        class: "added"
    }).addClass('circle').css({
        'top' : e.pageY - 20,
        'left' : e.pageX - 20
    }).appendTo('#result');
    i++;
});

$('#result').on('click','.circle',  function (e){
    if(remove == true){
        $(this).remove();
    }
    else{
        //just to see if it was clicked
        $(this).css({'background-color': 'red'});
    }
});
$('#btn').toggle(function() {
    $(this).text('Remove');
    remove = true;
}, function() {
    $(this).text('Add');
    remove = false;
});
```

fiddle here for the results http://jsfiddle.net/B6P76/

Answer (score 0):

you can use

> hide()

method from jquery

Comment: and jus how is that going to help ? where would the OP put this `hide()` method ? to resolve which problem ?