# Creating DIV on Button Click with input DATA and IMAGE like facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

I'm doing a project that consists of posting updates with photos, like facebook timeline. so i created this

[image]

So i need the code for the following:

When the POST button is clicked, **make a new DIV on the top of last post on the timeline that is similar to facebook. and the DIV must consist of Input text and the image that i uploaded.** when I browsed this topic I found similar thread [jQuery create and remove <div> by click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575081/jquery-create-and-remove-div-by-click) , but it creates divs one after another. I need just the opposite of that.

Any help will much appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to change the question a little bit, do you need help with creating a new div, or do you want to know information on how to save and retrieve your saved input text/image? If you need information on how to create a new div on click, take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zh3vpvot/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use prepend instead of append to put a new div on the beginning of a container:

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a **empty** `div` were you want them to appear (id: `#start`) and everytime you whant to post something, you can use jQuerys `after` (eg:`$("#start").after('<div>text and formating</div>');`).
You can see some more examples here: http://api.jquery.com/after/